# Null Pointer Exception At "@android:style/Widget.RatingBar

Tags: android, themes

i am trying to make a customized rating bar. for which i am trying to make a customized style

```
       <style
      name="customRatingbar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/layerlist_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
       </style>
```

layerlist_ratingbar is

```
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android">                                 

       <item android:id="@android:id/background"android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />

        <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />

        <item android:id="@android:id/progress"android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_fill" />

     </layer-list>
```

**rating_bar_empty:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_empty"></item>
<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_empty"
    ></item>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_empty" ></item>


  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_empty"></item>

   </selector>
```

**rating_bar_fill:**

```
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android">
    <item 
      android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_full"></item>
<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_full"
    ></item>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_window_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_full" ></item>


<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_rate_full"></item>
```

and my console looks alike

```
   12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.syntax.customratingbar/com.syntax.customratingbar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.RatingBar
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:167)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.RatingBar
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-10 15:30:05.540: E/AndroidRuntime(17129):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
```

**activity_main xml**

in xml i am just changing background of my rating bar

```
 <RatingBar 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@style/customRatingbar"
    android:numStars="4"
    android:rating="3.0"
    android:id="@+id/myRatingBar"
    android:isIndicator="true"/>
```

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.RatingBar

Comment: Post your `RatingBar` section  xml

Comment: ok give me a moment.

Comment: Check below answer .He is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
android:background="@style/customRatingbar"
```

to

```
style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
```

Comment: you are right .I deleted my answer .How "FAST" you are

Comment: i got this. but one more problem i tried to reduce the step size between two stars by android:stepSize="0.1" but it sounds to not work. any idea why?